# Installation messed up with Ruby: Unable to install jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I was trying to setup a GitHub Page using Jekyll, which rely on Ruby (like [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll#creating-a-repository-for-your-site)). Unfortunately, I think I kind of messed up with the installation (after a few `sudo apt-get install ruby-full` and `sudo apt-get remove ruby-full` ...)

Right now, I am stuck with an old version of Ruby (I think) on my computer that I am not able to update. Here is the state of my system right now:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
$ gem -v
3.1.2
```

```
$ gem install jekyll
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    The last version of sass-embedded (~> 1.54) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.58.0. Try installing it with `gem install sass-embedded -v 1.58.0` and then running the current command again
    sass-embedded requires RubyGems version >= 3.3.22. The current RubyGems version is 3.1.2. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.
```

```
$ gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.4.6
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.4.6
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 0 seconds
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.4.6
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 0 seconds
Installing RubyGems 3.4.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from setup.rb:22:in `<main>'
    4: from setup.rb:22:in `require'
    3: from /home/jarret/gems/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.6/lib/rubygems.rb:1332:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /home/jarret/gems/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.6/lib/rubygems.rb:1332:in `require'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:50:in `<class:Specification>': undefined method `rubyforge_project=' for class `Gem::Specification' (NameError)
    3: from setup.rb:22:in `<main>'
    2: from setup.rb:22:in `require'
    1: from /home/jarret/gems/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.6/lib/rubygems.rb:1328:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jarret/gems/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.6/lib/rubygems.rb:1342:in `rescue in <top (required)>': undefined method `rubyforge_project=' for class `Gem::Specification' (NameError)
Loading the /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb file caused an error. This file is owned by your OS, not by rubygems upstream. Please find out which OS package this file belongs to and follow the guidelines from your OS to report the problem and ask for help.
```

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.0 (2019-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jarret/gems
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jarret/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.7
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/jarret/gems/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/jarret/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/jarret/gems
     - /home/jarret/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
     - /var/lib/gems/2.7.0
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.7.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
     - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/jarret/gems/bin
     - /home/jarret/miniconda3/condabin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
     - /opt/fiji/Fiji.app
```

I've tried many remove/install, I've tried updated gem, ruby. Nothing unlocked me so far.

Comment: I'm thinking this is likely to be a `$PATH` issue. It looks like [`apt-get` does not modify your $PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360257/shouldnt-apt-get-modify-path).  Ruby is now up to [v3.2.1](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), so v2.7 is quite dated and I'd be surprised if that's what `apt-get` is installing by default.

Comment: @pjs The version of Ruby installed by package managers is typically the latest version of Ruby available at the time that version of the OS was initially released. For Ubuntu 20.04 that was Ruby 2.7.0 which was released in 2019.

Comment: You are using system Ruby. You don't explain how you installed Ruby 3.1 but it would appear you did not install it successfully. I would encourage you to read https://dontusesystemruby.com for a full explanation of this issue. You need to reinstall Ruby 3.1 and do so carefully following every single step of whatever instructions you choose to follow.

Comment: Thanks @anothermh, I installed Ruby using RVM (following the advices from the site you refered) and I managed to reinstall everything properly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Try to replace ruby3.0, sass1.58 is too advanced and may not be compatible with ruby2.7.
Please follow these steps and run the command.

1. `rvm install 3.0`
2. `rvm use 3.0.0 -default`
3. `rvm -v`
4. `rvm gemset update`
5. `gem install jekyll`
6. `jekyll -v`

Comment: This worked for me! Had the same exact problem as OP. Thanks for saving my day!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I kept using ruby 2.7 and managed to install `sass-embedded` with:

```bash
gem install sass-embedded -v 1.54
```